# Pass multiple variables to pug loop

Tags: pug

In some SCSS I've passed multiple variables to loop through some variations.

```
$row1ColTitle-bg--Colors: ("Red" #8f1324 #fff) ("Black" #000 #fff) ("Grey" #ccc #000) ("White" #fff #000);

@each $row in $rowTitlerow-bg--Colors {
$names: nth($row, 1);
$bgColor: nth($row, 2);
$txtColor: nth($row, 3);
```

I'd like to write out something similar for pug, and not sure how to tackle it.  Started with this, but need to incorporate the array of variables.

```
each varColor in ['Red', "Black", 'Grey', 'White']
  div(class="row1ColTitle  row1ColTitle-bg--" + varColor)
```

Assistance is appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem with what you have?  Looks fine to me.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the syntax of how I'd use the array in pug.   So the line,  'code' each varColor in ['Red', "Black", 'Grey', 'White']   how would I write that to use the variables within the pub loop.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide an example of the desired HTML to be output for each row.

Comment: Here's my codePen https://codepen.io/Johndgraham/pen/QzLOwJ?editors=1100 in the last line of of PUG I have button.rowButton__color--White there's where I'd like to utilize the array, so the last two rows of Grey and White, I can change that variable so the button is Red.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a guess here that you want to manipulate both the background color and button color.

First, you need to set up an array like this:

```
[
  {
    "background": "Red",
    "button": "White"
  },
  {
    "background": "Black",
    "button": "White"
  },
  {
    "background": "Grey",
    "button": "Black"
  },
  {
    "background": "White",
    "button": "Black"
  }
]
```

I'd recommend that the array lives in your route, but you can also squeeze it into your template.

Then, you can loop through it like this:

```
each color in theColors
  div(class="row1ColTitle  row1ColTitle-bg--" + color.background)
  ...
  button(class= "rowButton__color--" + color.button) Learn More
```